# Show $h(x)=1+4d(x,x_0)$ is continuous in a metric space $(X,d)$ and $(\mathbb R , |\cdot |) $

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $(X,d)$ and $(\mathbb R , |\cdot |) $ be metric spaces.
>
> Show that $h(x)=1+4d(x,x_0)$ is continuous.

I thing that a composition of continuous functions is continuous, but I don't think I can just use it.

I let $f=1$ and $g=d(x,x_0)$, then I need to show that $h=f+4g$ is continuous.

Now is $f=1$ continuous? I have to show for all $\epsilon > 0 \exists \delta >0$ s.t. $$d(x,x_0)<\delta \Rightarrow |1,1|<\epsilon$$

Since $|1-1|=0<\epsilon$ we are done. (Assuming I understand what $| \cdot |$ means correctly.

Now $d(x,x_0)$:

$$d(x,x_0)<\delta \Rightarrow |g(x),g(x_0)|<\epsilon$$

However I don't know how to show this inequality.

Another question: is $|4g(x),4g(x_0)|=4|g(x),g(x_0)|$? Is this true generally for Euclidian metric spaces? I don't think it works for discrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that the function $d(x,x_0)$ a function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. To that end show that for any $x,y\in X$ we have that $$|d(x,x_0)-d(y,x_0)|\leq d(x,y)$$ so that proving continuity of $h$ becomes trivial. For example one half of the inequality can be shown using the fact that $$d(x,x_0)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,x_0).$$

Comment: I don't understand why $|d(x,x_0)-d(y,x_0)|\leq d(x,y)$ is sufficient. I'm assuming this proves continuity, which my book says is for all $\epsilon \exists \delta >0$ s.t. $d(x,x_0)\Rightarrow | x-x_0 |<\epsilon $

Comment: Also, is the last inequality meants to be triangle inequality, but you mistaked $y_0$ for $x_0$?

Comment: To prove the continuity of $d(x,x_0)$ you have to show that $\forall\epsilon>0\,\forall x\,\exists\delta>0\,\forall y: d(x,y)<\delta\implies |d(x,x_0)-d(y,y_0)|<\epsilon$